Showing C++ objects on a QML scene
Changing a QGraphicsScene / QGraphicsItem collection to use QML... I am recreating the items in the backend, and trying to place them in a Repeater on the QML frontend.
My items are inheriting QQuickItem. (I even tried to inherit the private more similar object types, this may not be the final option but should be easier to place fully created items. The items used can be any QQuickItem subclasses.) There is no intermediate common class type - so I don't have a name to give the objects in the delegate, other than Item.
I can get information about their content, I can place a single created item on the canvas, but I don't know how to place an entire model on the QML canvas.
Please take a look at my example, and help me get my items on the scene (in the Repeater)

main.cpp:
#include "backend.h"
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#define APP_URI "uri.dlitems"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<Backend>(APP_URI, 1, 0, "Backend", [](QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine *) {return new Backend();});    // To show with model
    qmlRegisterType<TextItem>(APP_URI, 1, 0, "MyTextItem");   // To show stand-alone without model
    qmlRegisterType<RectangleItem>(APP_URI, 1, 0, "MyRectangleItem");
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) { if (!obj && url == objUrl) QCoreApplication::exit(-1); }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();
}

main.qml:
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import uri.dlitems 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
    id: proofRoot
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 545
    property list<QtObject> myModel: Backend.model
    MyTextItem {}   // To show the items themselves like I want with the repeater
    MyRectangleItem {}
    Rectangle {
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            top: parent.top
            margins: 20
        }
        height: 150
        width: 500
        ListView {    // To show that the model is accessible and I can get item info in QML
            id: listView
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 20
            spacing: 10
            model: proofRoot.myModel
            delegate: Item {
                id: myItem
                required property string itemType
                width: label.width
                height: label.height
                Text {
                    text: myItem.itemType
                    font.pointSize: 24
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
            margins: 20
        }
        height: 350
        Repeater {   // This is actually what I want - a way to display the items as above but using a model
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 20
            model: proofRoot.myModel
            delegate: Item {
// No idea what to do here
// I want to show the elements from the model with their properties from c++
            }
        }
    }
}

backend.h:
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <private/qquicktext_p.h>
#include <private/qquickrectangle_p.h>

class TextItem : public QQuickText
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString itemType MEMBER m_itemType NOTIFY itemTypeChanged)
public:
    TextItem() : QQuickText(Q_NULLPTR), m_itemType("TextItem") {
        setText("TextItem");
        setPosition(QPointF(10, 10));
        setSize(QSizeF(100, 20));
        QFont f;
        f.setItalic(true);
        f.setPointSize(16);
        setFont(f);
    }
signals:
    void itemTypeChanged();
private:
    QString m_itemType;
};

class RectangleItem : public QQuickRectangle
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString itemType MEMBER m_itemType NOTIFY itemTypeChanged)
public:
    RectangleItem() : QQuickRectangle(Q_NULLPTR), m_itemType("RectangleItem") {
        setPosition(QPointF(40, 120));
        setSize(QSizeF(100, 50));
        setColor(Qt::red);
        QQuickPen *pen = border();
        pen->setWidth(2);
        pen->setColor(Qt::black);
    }
signals:
    void itemTypeChanged();
private:
    QString m_itemType;
};

class Backend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject *> model MEMBER m_model NOTIFY modelChanged)
    QML_ELEMENT
    QML_SINGLETON
public:
    explicit Backend(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject{parent} {
        m_model.append(new TextItem());
        m_model.append(new RectangleItem());
    }
    virtual ~Backend() override {
        for (QObject *item : m_model) delete item;
    }
signals:
    void modelChanged();
private:
    QList<QObject *> m_model;
};
#endif // BACKEND_H


I think you have described the problem wrong. It has nothing to do with C++ objects. The problem seems to be that you want to use a Repeater and have it generate multiple types of delegates at the same time, depending on the contents of the model. Repeaters only want to create a single type of delegate. But there are workarounds that have already been discussed on this site. Try this one.

@JarMan: Thanks I will try it like that - but my ListView did not have any problem with items of multiple kinds, I thought because they had a common base QQuickItem

Your ListView is not displaying different kinds of delegates. Every delegate there is an Item with Text inside. It pulls data from the same model, but it is not trying to display the items from that model, while your Repeater is. Also, as a general rule, the model should just be a list of data, not a list of visual items. That way you can choose to display the data in multiple views if you want without altering the model.

@JarMan I don't want to display the data. My intention is to display - and interact with - the items. That is why they inherit from the QQuickitem specialized classes. I am still working on it, my Repeater is not behaving. But thanks, I understand now why the ListView was able to display properly.
